# Reputation 10 to post images, but there are no images

Tags: discussion, support, bug, reputation

I get this 'you need at least 10 reputation to post images' message even though I have not included any images at all, only two links, some tags and two code snippets.

What am I doing wrong?

This 'source code' of my post that caused the named error message:

```
Background
=
I am currently working on my bachelor thesis and basically my task is to optimise a given code in [tag:go], i.e. make it run as fast as possible. First, I optimised the serial function and then tried to introduce parallelism via goroutines. After researching on the internet I now understand the difference between concurrency and parallelism thanks to the following slides from golang talks. I visited some parallel programming courses where we parallelised a c/c++ code with help of pthread/openmp, thus I tried to apply these paradigms in [tag:go]. That said, in this particular case I am optimising a function which computes the moving average of a slice with length `len:=n+(window_size-1)` (it equals either 9393 or 10175), hence we have `n` windows of which we compute the corresponding arithmetic average and save that properly in the output slice.  

Note that this task is inherently embarrassing parallel.  

My optimisation attempts and results
=
In `moving_avg_concurrent2` I split up the slice into `num_goroutines` smaller pieces and ran each with one goroutine. This function performed with one goroutine, out of some reason (could not find out why yet, but we are getting tangent here), better than `moving_avg_serial4` but with more than one goroutine it started to perform worse than `moving_avg_serial4`.  
In `moving_avg_concurrent3` I adopted the master/worker paradigm. The performance was worse than `moving_avg_serial4` when using one goroutine. Here we at least I got a better performance when increasing `num_goroutines` but still not better than `moving_avg_serial4`.
To compare the performances of `moving_avg_serial4`, `moving_avg_concurrent2` and `moving_avg_concurrent3` I wrote a benchmark and I tabulated the results:  

fct & num_goroutines | timing in ns/op | percentage  
\---------------------------------------------------------------------   
serial4 | 4357893 | 100.00%  
concur2_1 | 5174818 |   118.75%  
concur2_4 | 9986386 |   229.16%  
concur2_8 | 18973443 |  435.38%  
concur2_32 |    75602438 |  1734.84%  
concur3_1 | 32423150 |  744.01%  
concur3_4 | 21083897 |  483.81%  
concur3_8 | 16427430 |  376.96%  
concur3_32 |    15157314 |  347.81%  

Question
=
Since as mentioned above this problem is embarrassingly parallel I was expecting to see a tremendous performance increase but that was not the case.  

Why does `moving_avg_concurrent2` not scale at all?  
And why is `moving_avg_concurrent3` that much slower than `moving_avg_serial4`?  
I know that goroutines are cheap but still are not free, but is it possible that this generates that much overhead such that we are even slower than `moving_avg_serial4`?

Code
-
Functions:  

    // returns a slice containing the moving average of the input (given, i.e. not optimised)
    func moving_avg_serial(input []float64, window_size int) []float64 {
        first_time := true
        var output = make([]float64, len(input))
        if len(input) > 0 {
            var buffer = make([]float64, window_size)
            // initialise buffer with NaN
            for i := range buffer {
                buffer[i] = math.NaN()
            }
            for i, val := range input {
                old_val := buffer[int((math.Mod(float64(i), float64(window_size))))]
                buffer[int((math.Mod(float64(i), float64(window_size))))] = val
                if !NaN_in_slice(buffer) && first_time {
                    sum := 0.0
                    for _, entry := range buffer {
                        sum += entry
                    }
                    output[i] = sum / float64(window_size)
                    first_time = false
                } else if i > 0 && !math.IsNaN(output[i-1]) && !NaN_in_slice(buffer) {
                    output[i] = output[i-1] + (val-old_val)/float64(window_size) // solution without loop
                } else {
                    output[i] = math.NaN()
                }
            }
        } else { // empty input
            fmt.Println("moving_avg is panicking!")
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", input))
        }
        return output
    }

    // returns a slice containing the moving average of the input
    // reordering the control structures to exploid the short-circuit evaluation
    func moving_avg_serial4(input []float64, window_size int) []float64 {
        first_time := true
        var output = make([]float64, len(input))
        if len(input) > 0 {
            var buffer = make([]float64, window_size)
            // initialise buffer with NaN
            for i := range buffer {
                buffer[i] = math.NaN()
            }
            for i := range input {
                //            fmt.Printf("in mvg_avg4: i=%v\n", i)
                old_val := buffer[int((math.Mod(float64(i), float64(window_size))))]
                buffer[int((math.Mod(float64(i), float64(window_size))))] = input[i]
                if first_time && !NaN_in_slice(buffer) {
                    sum := 0.0
                    for j := range buffer {
                        sum += buffer[j]
                    }
                    output[i] = sum / float64(window_size)
                    first_time = false
                } else if i > 0 && !math.IsNaN(output[i-1]) /* && !NaN_in_slice(buffer)*/ {
                    output[i] = output[i-1] + (input[i]-old_val)/float64(window_size) // solution without loop
                } else {
                    output[i] = math.NaN()
                }
            }
        } else { // empty input
            fmt.Println("moving_avg is panicking!")
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", input))
        }
        return output
    }

    // returns a slice containing the moving average of the input
    // splitting up slice into smaller pieces for the goroutines but without using the serial version, i.e. we only have NaN's in the beginning, thus hope to reduce some overhead
    // still does not scale (decreasing performance with increasing size and num_goroutines)
    func moving_avg_concurrent2(input []float64, window_size, num_goroutines int) []float64 {
        var output = make([]float64, window_size-1, len(input))
        for i := 0; i < window_size-1; i++ {
            output[i] = math.NaN()
        }
        if len(input) > 0 {
            num_items := len(input) - (window_size - 1)
            var barrier_wg sync.WaitGroup
            n := num_items / num_goroutines
            go_avg := make([][]float64, num_goroutines)
            for i := 0; i < num_goroutines; i++ {
                go_avg[i] = make([]float64, 0, num_goroutines)
            }

            for i := 0; i < num_goroutines; i++ {
                barrier_wg.Add(1)
                go func(go_id int) {
                    defer barrier_wg.Done()

                    // computing boundaries
                    var start, stop int
                    start = go_id*int(n) + (window_size - 1) // starting index
                    // ending index
                    if go_id != (num_goroutines - 1) {
                        stop = start + n // Ending index
                    } else {
                        stop = num_items + (window_size - 1) // Ending index
                    }

                    loc_avg := moving_avg_serial4(input[start-(window_size-1):stop], window_size)

                    loc_avg = make([]float64, stop-start)
                    current_sum := 0.0
                    for i := start - (window_size - 1); i < start+1; i++ {
                        current_sum += input[i]
                    }
                    loc_avg[0] = current_sum / float64(window_size)
                    idx := 1

                    for i := start + 1; i < stop; i++ {
                        loc_avg[idx] = loc_avg[idx-1] + (input[i]-input[i-(window_size)])/float64(window_size)
                        idx++
                    }

                    go_avg[go_id] = append(go_avg[go_id], loc_avg...)

                }(i)
            }
            barrier_wg.Wait()

            for i := 0; i < num_goroutines; i++ {
                output = append(output, go_avg[i]...)
            }

        } else { // empty input
            fmt.Println("moving_avg is panicking!")
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", input))
        }
        return output
    }

    // returns a slice containing the moving average of the input
    // change of paradigm, we opt for a master worker pattern and spawn all windows which each will be computed by a goroutine
    func compute_window_avg(input, output []float64, start, end int) {
        sum := 0.0
        size := end - start
        for _, val := range input[start:end] {
            sum += val
        }
        output[end-1] = sum / float64(size)
    }

    func moving_avg_concurrent3(input []float64, window_size, num_goroutines int) []float64 {
        var output = make([]float64, window_size-1, len(input))
        for i := 0; i < window_size-1; i++ {
            output[i] = math.NaN()
        }
        if len(input) > 0 {
            num_windows := len(input) - (window_size - 1)
            var output = make([]float64, len(input))
            for i := 0; i < window_size-1; i++ {
                output[i] = math.NaN()
            }

            pending := make(chan *Work)
            done := make(chan *Work)

            // creating work
            go func() {
                for i := 0; i < num_windows; i++ {
                    pending <- NewWork(compute_window_avg, input, output, i, i+window_size)
                }
            }()

            // start goroutines which work through pending till there is nothing left
            for i := 0; i < num_goroutines; i++ {
                go func() {
                    Worker(pending, done)
                }()
            }

            // wait till every work is done
            for i := 0; i < num_windows; i++ {
                <-done
            }

            return output

        } else { // empty input
            fmt.Println("moving_avg is panicking!")
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", input))
        }
        return output
    }

Benchmarks:  

    //############### BENCHMARKS ###############
    var import_data_res11 []float64
    func benchmarkMoving_avg_serial(b *testing.B, window int) {
        var r []float64
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            r = moving_avg_serial(BackTest_res.F["Trading DrawDowns"], window)
        }
        import_data_res11 = r
    }

    var import_data_res14 []float64
    func benchmarkMoving_avg_serial4(b *testing.B, window int) {
        var r []float64
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            r = moving_avg_serial4(BackTest_res.F["Trading DrawDowns"], window)
        }
        import_data_res14 = r
    }

    var import_data_res16 []float64
    func benchmarkMoving_avg_concurrent2(b *testing.B, window, num_goroutines int) {
        var r []float64
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            r = moving_avg_concurrent2(BackTest_res.F["Trading DrawDowns"], window, num_goroutines)
        }
        import_data_res16 = r
    }

    var import_data_res17 []float64
    func benchmarkMoving_avg_concurrent3(b *testing.B, window, num_goroutines int) {
        var r []float64
        for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
            r = moving_avg_concurrent3(BackTest_res.F["Trading DrawDowns"], window, num_goroutines)
        }
        import_data_res17 = r
    }



    func BenchmarkMoving_avg_serial_261x10(b *testing.B) {
        benchmarkMoving_avg_serial(b, 261*10)
    }

    func BenchmarkMoving_avg_serial4_261x10(b *testing.B) {
        benchmarkMoving_avg_serial4(b, 261*10)
    }


    func BenchmarkMoving_avg_concurrent2_261x10_1(b *testing.B) {
        benchmarkMoving_avg_concurrent2(b, 261*10, 1)
    }
    func BenchmarkMoving_avg_concurrent2_261x10_8(b *testing.B) {
        benchmarkMoving_avg_concurrent2(b, 261*10, 8)
    }


    func BenchmarkMoving_avg_concurrent3_261x10_1(b *testing.B) {
        benchmarkMoving_avg_concurrent3(b, 261*10, 1)
    }
    func BenchmarkMoving_avg_concurrent3_261x10_8(b *testing.B) {
        benchmarkMoving_avg_concurrent3(b, 261*10, 8)
    }
    //############### BENCHMARKS end ###############
```

Remarks:
This is my very first post, I am still learning, so any constructive criticism is also welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to remove the reference to `[tag:go]` at the beginning. It is a [sponsored tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) which means it has an image incorporated into it when it gets displayed as a tag. But regardless of that, there really isn't any reason for you to link it as a tag like that, as it doesn't add any additional value to your question and just makes the sentence slightly harder to read. Just saying "Go" without the tag rendering is fine. I'd assume you're already adding the actual tag to your question which provides all the functionality in the appropriate place.

Comment: But that sponsored image doesn't seem to appear anywhere while editing or even when the post is rendered. It only appears in the tag under the question. Shouldn't this be considered as a bug?

Comment: Thank you very much, I removed these two tags and it finally worked for me!

Comment: @rene It doesn't show up in the preview (we don't bother to look it up there), but it definitely does show up once rendered into the post.

Comment: Ah, the server side render picks it up, fair enough @animuson